# How to manipulate the index in one dataframe and filter for indices in another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I started learning pandas and stuck at below issue:

I have two large DataFrames:
df1=

```
ID                                 KRAS        ATM
TCGA-3C-AAAU-01A-11R-A41B-07       101         32
TCGA-3C-AALI-01A-11R-A41B-07       101         75
TCGA-3C-AALJ-01A-31R-A41B-07       102         65
TCGA-3C-ARLJ-01A-61R-A41B-07       87          54
```

df2=

```
ID                                 BRCA1        ATM
TCGA-A1-A0SP                       54           65
TCGA-3C-AALI                       191          8
TCGA-3C-AALJ                       37           68
```

The ID is the index in both df. First, I want to cut the name of the ID to only the first 10 digits ( convert TCGA-3C-AAAU-01A-11R-A41B-07 to TCGA-3C-AAAU) in df1. Then I want to produce a new df from df1 which has the ID that exist in df2.

df3 should look:

```
 ID                                KRAS        ATM 
TCGA-3C-AALI                       101         75 
TCGA-3C-AALJ                       102         65
```

I tried different ways but failed. Any suggestions on this, please?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC TCGA-3C-AAAU this contain 12 character :-)

```
df3=df1.assign(ID=df1.ID.str[:12]).loc[lambda x:x.ID.isin(df2.ID),:]
df3
Out[218]: 
             ID  KRAS  ATM
1  TCGA-3C-AALI   101   75
2  TCGA-3C-AALJ   102   65
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using vectorised functions:

```
# truncate to first 10 characters, or 12 including '-'
df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].str[:12]

# filter for IDs in df2
df3 = df1[df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])]
```

**Result**

```
             ID  KRAS  ATM
1  TCGA-3C-AALI   101   75
2  TCGA-3C-AALJ   102   65
```

**Explanation**

- Use `.str` accessor to limit `df1['ID']` to first 12 characters.
- Mask `df1` to include only IDs found in `df2`.